# ROUND() givin incorrect result in sql

Tags: sql-server, oracle, t-sql, rounding

```
select round(849299099755.3,2) from dual;
```

Gives

```
849299099755.3
```

How can I get `849299099755.30` here???

Comment: What [RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system) you are using? `SQL Server`? `MySQL`? `Oracle`? `DB2`? etc..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

convert the datatype onto `DECIMAL`

```
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(15,2), ROUND(849299099755.3,2))
```

or

```
SELECT STR(ROUND(849299099755.3,2), 20, 2)
```

Comment: This works fine for me!!! However, when I tried executing same in ORACLE it gave me error - ORA-00936: missing expression, As decimal is also supported in oracle, what is the reason for error?

Comment: what's the reason for unaccepting? because I ask you about the RDBMS and you told me `SQL Server`.

Answer (score 1):

For `SQL Server`:

```
select convert(numeric(28,2),round(849299099755.3,2)) from dual;
```

Answer (score 1):

For Oracle:

The ROUND function returns a NUMBER, and `round(849299099755.3,2)` indeed is equal to `849299099755.3`, so it's working correctly. When you want to display it, however, it will use your session's default number format setting.

To format it with two decimal places, you could use the `TO_CHAR` function, e.g.:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(round(849299099755.3,2),'999999999990.00') FROM DUAL;
```